# Declaring a constructor parameter which is assignable to Type in C#

Tags: c#, types

I'm trying to write a constructor which accepts some `Type` but not all of them.

Currently:

```
public MyClass(Type type)
{
    this.Type = type;
}
```

I want to:

```
public MyClass(typeof(IMyInterface) type)
{
    this.Type = type;
}
```

Of course, it doesn't compile.

Is there any way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: You could check `type` implements the right interface and throw a runtime exception but I'd question why you want to do this in the first place. This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: If you want type parameters that usually indicates a switch to using generics. But you can't just have a generic constructor.

Comment: This is probably an X/Y question, it would help if you stated _why_ you need this.

Comment: Well, first of all, it's very clear what I'm asking, I can't understand why did you flag. Maybe an XY problem, yes, but to make it simple and very clear, I omitted the reason *why* I want to do this. So I can decide if it's XY or not myself, instead of asking you to solve *my specific problem*, which I think not what SO community prefer. @Henk Holterman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have dynamic filters like this. You can supply an instance if you want to: there you could use the interface as a type name.

Otherwise you could throw an exception, or use generics in order to make sure only a specific type is supplied.

From an instance:

```
public MyClass(IMyInterface instance)
{
    this.Type = instance.GetType();
}
```

An exception:

```
public MyClass(Type type)
{
    if (!(typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    this.Type = type;
}
```

Generics are shown in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a type constructor, you want a generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: IMyInterface
{
}
```

Now you can initialize this class with any other type that implements that interface:

```
var sample = new MyClass<OtherClass>();
```

---

```
public class OtherClass : IMyInterface
{
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right.  Just wanted to make sure if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.